# Angularjs with $resource and $scope

Tags: angularjs, scope, angular-resource

I have the following two methods getP and getPage ,getP get data by $resource from database and set $scope.mydata from output,i need to use this output in other method getPage so I call the two method in contoller ,

the probelm I cant get data in second method ,console.log($scope.mydata) get null

```
     $scope.mydata={};
      var sasa;
      var page=0; var size=100;

     $scope.getP = function() {
           sasa=$resource('api/testrecordajaxs/:page/:size', {
                page : page,
                size : size
            }).query();
            $scope.mydata=sasa;
          }; 

           var getPage = function() {
              console.log($scope.mydata) //get null 
              var firstRow = (paginationOptions.pageNumber - 1) * paginationOptions.pageSize;
              $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.mydata.slice(firstRow, firstRow + paginationOptions.pageSize);
            };


          $scope.getP();
          getPage();
```

Comment: Ofcourse it's not defined yet, you don't wait for the data to come back from `$resource`. Also, the way you define `sasa` looks kindof wrong. Read up on how to use `$resource`, and `promises` in angular.

Answer (score 0):

You should use promises (notice that function `getP` returns promise):

```js
$scope.mydata = {};
var sasa;
var page = 0;
var size = 100;

$scope.getP = function() {
  return $resource('api/testrecordajaxs/:page/:size', {
    page: page,
    size: size
  }).query().then(function(data) {
    $scope.mydata = data;
    return data;
  });
};

var getPage = function(data) {
  console.log($scope.mydata) // you can use data also 
  var firstRow = (paginationOptions.pageNumber - 1) * paginationOptions.pageSize;
  $scope.gridOptions.data = $scope.mydata.slice(firstRow, firstRow + paginationOptions.pageSize);
};
$scope.getP().then(getPage);
```

Comment: I made your changes but get this error  $resource(...).query(...).then is not a function

Comment: I just copied your sample of code and "promisified". So if there was a function `query` before, then it should be after changes. Check your code.

Comment: In older versions of Angular, `.success()` was how you'd catch when a promise resolved.  In newer versions it was changed to `.then()` to mirror the standard promise spec.

Answer (score 0):

I should wait for the data to come back from server then use it,so before using data in

```
    $scope.gridOptions.data = data.slice(firstRow, firstRow + paginationOptions.pageSize);
```

I used

```
      data.$promise.then(function(result)
```

So this code works fine with me

```
          var page=0; var size=100;

          var getData=$resource('api/testrecordajaxs/:page/:size', {
                page : '@page',
                size : '@size'
           });

          function getPage() {
             var data=getData.query({page:page,size:size});
               data.$promise.then(function(result) {
               var firstRow = (paginationOptions.pageNumber - 1) * paginationOptions.pageSize;
               $scope.gridOptions.data = data.slice(firstRow, firstRow + paginationOptions.pageSize);
            });
          }
          getPage();
```

Comment: I did something similar but the $scope.variable still no been set outside the promise